# R: barplot inconsistent width

Tags: r

I have two sets of data

```
Co1 Col2
1    10
2    12
3    13
4    14
5    15
6    16
7    17
8    18
9    19
```

I put these two data into two variables `Num` and `Leaf` respectively
and I tried to plot them with `barplot(Leaf,Num, space=0.5,col="red")`

Everything is fine, besides that some bars have larger width than the others. While some other bars have no width and literablly became a line.

Why is that?

I know i can fix it by doing `barplot(Leaf,Num, space=0.5,col="red", width=0.5)`

But I am wondering why the default behavior of such function gives you inconsistent bar width

Comment: Are you after a *bar*plot or a *box*plot? In case of the former, I'm unsure about your expected output. Do you expect to get a bar for every row, and then stack (or dodge?) bars from `Col1` and `Col2`?

Comment: @MauritsEvers it is barplot. The problem with the graph is that, I am not sure why without provide width argument, every bar will have different width.

Comment: In that case I don't understand what you're trying to plot (see my previous comment). What do you expect bars to denote? Do you expect to have a bar for every row and for every column?

Comment: You have literally provided `barplot(height=dat$Co1, width=dat$Col2)` as the first two arguments to your call. You are getting different widths because that is what you asked R to plot for you.

Comment: @thelatemail I am confused, I did not supply height and width argument in my barplot()

Comment: @MauritsEvers the graph is fine. I was just trying to figure out why, when the each column of the graph has different width.

Comment: *"I am confused, I did not supply height and width argument in my barplot()"* Yes you did, see `?barplot`. The first argument of `barplot` is a `vector` or a `matrix` (in your case `vector` `dat$Col1` or `Leaf`), and the second argument is an optional vector of bar widths (which you provide in your example as `dat$Col2` or `Num`).

Comment: *"the graph is fine. I was just trying to figure out why, when the each column of the graph has different width"* You don't answer *any* of my questions. It's very difficult to help if we don't know what it is you're trying to plot.

Comment: @MauritsEvers Just bar graph, Col1 will be my x axis and Col2 will be my y axis. I was able to see the graph use the code I have above. However, each column has different column width and I was trying to figure out why the width was not unviersal. Now you explained it, it makes sense now.

Comment: @MauritsEvers or is there a better way to graph this using barplot?

Comment: @aDev Ok now I understood what you're trying to do. I've added a base R and `ggplot` answer below, please take a look.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In base R you can do

```
barplot(df$Col2, names.arg = df$Co1)
```

[image]

Or using `ggplot`

```
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(df, aes(as.factor(Co1), Col2)) + geom_col() + xlab("Co1")
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

```
dataset = data.frame(Leaf,Num)
barplot(dataset$Leaf,dataset$Num,space=0.5,col="red")
```

or

```
barplot(Leaf,Num,space=0.5,col="red")
```